# Keeping an always-running ib_insync connection with Sanic

Tags: python, python-asyncio, interactive-brokers, sanic

I'm developing an API (using Sanic) which is a gateway to IB, using ib_insync
This API exposes endpoints to place a new order and getting live positions, but also is in charge to update order statuses in a DB using the events of ib_insync.

My question is - is it possible to have the API connect only once to IB when it goes up, and re-using the same connection for all requests?

I'm currently connecting to IB using `connectAsync` on every request. And while this is working - the API will not receive events if not currently handling a request.

This is one endpoint code, for reference

```
@app.post("/order/<symbol>")
async def post_order(request, symbol):
    order = jsonpickle.decode(request.body)
    with await IB().connectAsync("127.0.0.1", 7496, clientId=100) as ib:
        ib.orderStatusEvent += onOrderStatus
        ib.errorEvent += onTWSError
        ib.newOrderEvent += onNewOrderEvent

        contract = await ib.qualifyContractsAsync(contract)
        trade = ib.placeOrder(contract[0], order)

    return text(trade.order.orderId)
```

So I wish to not use the `with` statement, and just use a global ib connection.

When I'm connecting on the module init (using `connectAsync`), every later call that is async, like `qualifyContractsAsync`, just hangs. Debugging showed me that it hangs on `asyncio.gather` which means I'm doing something wrong with the event loops.

Comment: If you need connection for long time, you can try websockets.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a bit rude here - but this seems irrelevant for my specific issue. ib_insync is running WebSocket behind the scenes, and the question is how to keep the IB connection alive between requests. Changing my REST API to be WS API isn't really a solution.

Comment: well, this is not rude at all, thanks for good feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this particular connection, but yes it should be possible. Presumably the `with` statement is opening and closing the connection.

Instead, open and close it with a listener.

[Docs re: listeners](https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/basics/listeners.html)

```py
@app.before_server_start
async def connect(app,_):
    app.ctx.foo = await Foobar()

@app.route("/")
async def handler(request):
    await request.app.ctx.foo.do_something()

@app.after_server_stop
async def close(app,_):
    app.ctx.foo.close()
```